# What are the repercussions of the Sword Coast Adventurers Guide errata to the cantrips Green-Flame Blade and Booming Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, errata

In the [most recent](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SCAG-Errata.pdf) errata update to the Sword Coast Adventurers guide, *Green-Flame Blade* and *Booming Blade* have received errata to their range and spell text, being altered from

> *Range: 5 feet*

to

> *Range: Self (5 foot radius)*

Furthermore, the text of *GFB* and *BB* have been altered from

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails.

to the phrase

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell’s casting and make
> a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you.

How do these changes alter the way that these spells are used, and how they interact with features or feats, such as Spell Snipers effect of doubling a spells range.

Comment: You might have missed that, for the material component, the weapon now has to have a value of at least 1sp.

Comment: This feels too broad and a duplicate of existing questions that just need to be updated to reflect the errata.

Comment: I think this should be closed. It's asking about lots of interactions, which if asked individually, most would be closed as dupes of questions that are being or have been updated already.

Comment: I think lots of other questions should be closed as a duplicate of this question that is suited to the stack and well within scope. I voted to leave open -from review.

Comment: @NautArch sure, when I organically come across them and remember this question, then I will vote them as duplicates. A question that consolidates lots of cases also leaves room for more specific questions about cases that don't fit the general question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Distant Spell and Spell Sniper do not work.

The sorcerer's distant spell metamagic says:

> When you cast a spell that has a range of 5 feet or greater, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double the range of the spell.

Spell Sniper says:

> When you cast a spell that requires you to make an attack roll, the spell’s range is doubled.

Having a range of *self* means these features no longer work with *BB* and *GFB*.

#### War Caster does not work.

War Caster says:

> When a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack. The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and *must target only that creature*.

Since *BB* and *GFB* now have a range of self, they target the caster, not "only that creature" as required by War Caster.

It should be noted that lead rules desiugner Jeremy Crawford has stated on twitter that his intent is that War Caster would still work with *booming blade*.

#### Twinned spell does not work.

Twinned Spell metamagic says:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn’t have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).

Twinned Spell doesn't work with a range of self.

#### Clearer interaction with a new Bladesinger feature.

In the same errata, the Bladesinger Wizard received a change to its Extra Attack ability:

> Starting at 6th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn. **Moreover, you can cast one of your cantrips in place of one of those attacks.**

The removal of the phrase "as part of the action used to cast this spell" makes the interaction between this feature and *BB* or *GFB* more clear - the spell is not being cast with the *Cast a Spell* action, rather it is being cast in place of an attack as part of an attack action.

#### They probably don't work with most improvised weapons.

The material component was changed as well, from "a weapon", to:

> a melee weapon worth at least 1 sp

So if you are using an improvised melee weapon, it must be worth at least 1 sp or you can't use *BB* or *GFB*. For example, a rock isn't but a table might be. Of course, your DM may interpret "a melee weapon worth at least 1 sp" as requiring it to have a value *as* a melee weapon - a table might be worth 10 gp as a table but nothing as a weapon. Your DM may also say that a table used as an improvised weapon is [not actually a melee weapon at all](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119926).

*This also means they do not work with the spell shadow blade*.

#### A definitive answer to the question about standing up from prone.

See here: [Does standing up from prone trigger the secondary damage from the Booming Blade cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73552/does-standing-up-from-prone-trigger-the-secondary-damage-from-the-booming-blade)

Now, *BB* reads:

> If the target willingly moves 5 feet or more before then,
> the target takes 1d8 thunder damage, and the spell ends.

It is now abundantly clear that standing up from prone does not trigger the secondary damage.

#### Counterspell *probably* works.

With the original wording, there was some question as to whether the melee attack was part of the spell (and thus countered by *counterspell*) or part of the somatic component (implying that the *counterspell* would counter any extra damage but the attack would still go through). This has been discussed at length in this Q&A: [If Booming Blade or Green Flame Blade are counterspelled, does the attack still go through?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177158/62294)

With the new errata, the concensus there seems to be shifting toward *counterspell* stopping the attack entirely.

---

For further reading, and seeing some interpretations that differ from those mentioned here; some of the above questions (and others) have been addressed elsewhere:

- [Can the spell Booming Blade be affected by the Twinned Spell metamagic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177342)
- [What is the difference between a spell with a range of "Self" and a spell with a range of "Self (XYZ)"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177381)
- [Do Booming Blade and the Spell Sniper feat stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114080)
- [Does standing up from prone trigger the secondary damage from the Booming Blade cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73552)
- [Are Improvised Weapons used in melee actually melee weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119926)
- [Do natural weapons work with the Booming Blade spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158889)
- [Does the material component of Booming blade need to the same one used in the attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177349)
- [Can the blade created by Shadow Blade be used with the Booming Blade or Green Flame Blade cantrips?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177347)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116150/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-markov-what-are-the-repercussions-of-the-sword-co). Feel free to continue to use it for the work on and around this answer.

Comment: This is wrong, at least in reference to War Caster: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1326595384790056960

Comment: @Nacht Jeremy Crawford is wrong :P, I’ll edit the answer to mention his tweet, but I think he’s wrong about his own rules.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov haha okay fair enough. Does that mean you consider Burning Hands to target the spellcaster?

Comment: Even in the errata, _booming blade_ and _green flame blade_ refer to the creature being attacked as "the target".